# BadAuthentication error while uploading video on youtube

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, youtube, gdata

My app is uploading videos on youtube using GData, Integrated before 1.5 years before. It was working fine till 4 days ago. but suddenly it stop uploading videos. I check and found that it is given bellow error.

```
Error while uploading video 403 == com.google.GDataServiceDomain
{
    Error = BadAuthentication;
    error = BadAuthentication;
    Info  = WebLoginRequired;
}
```

i tried to login with my username and password on youtube web site and gives me this error.

***Your password is correct, but we no longer support signing in with your YouTube username. Please enter your Google Account email address (************) to sign in.***\

so given my email address instead for username then it gives this error.

```
com.google.GDataServiceDomain
{
    Error = BadAuthentication;
    Info = WebLoginRequired;
    Url = "https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?service=youtube#Email=**%40**.com";
    error = BadAuthentication;
}
```

any guide how to fix this problem without releasing new version to app store, I am providing username and password for youtube using a web services hosted on my server.

Comment: Exactly same issue here with my app as well. It was working fine since 6 months and suddenly got the above mentioned error last month. Trying to figure out, but unable to fix. It is really urgent, since we have a release this month.

Comment: if you find a solution then please do inform me too.

Answer (score 0):

Login to google and turn on here
https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps